# Output of Get-content as variable?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I am attempting to run a foreach loop on a get-content and convertfrom-json cmd. Now im aware this potentially has issues being multiple value results in the variable, im wondering how i can continue to pass this info to the rest of the script.

```
$testconv = Get-device * |select ID
$testid = $testconv.id

$conv = foreach ($id in $testid) 
{
get-content "\\HDC-PRTG-03\System Information Database\Services\Device$id.Services" | Convertfrom-json 
} 

$rpccheck =$conv.message
$snmpcheck = $conv.message
$svcname = $conv.data.displayname
$svcstate=$conv.data.properties.state

if($RPCon = $rpccheck |select-string -pattern RPC -AllMatches){
write-host RPC Not enabled
}else{
write-host No RPC Enabled - Moving to Services List
```

Now when i run that with out the $conv= making it a variable it returns

```
kind         : Services 
recievetime  : 29-01-2018 14:43:32
error        : 106
Message      : SNMP Channels Not Available.
```

Which is what i expect. However when i define it a variable with $conv= it just starts to say it cannot find the file paths which i find an odd error to throw but hey ho.

Do any of you smart guys have any pointers for how i can keep these fromjson objects in memory so i can continue to run foreach loops against them. The ultiumate function of this script is to query a local .services file for what services are running on the device and then create sensors to monitor them within our PRTG installation. Therefore i need to be able to ref the deviceID and apply things to it.

I suspect i may be using too many foreach loops in the whole script but frankly i am 100% out of my depth

any guidance hugely hugely appreciated

Sam

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you should have json files for all device ID's. If a file with the name of a particular device is missing you will get the 'File not found' error.

As for the code, you can try this:

```
$testconv = Get-Device * | select ID
$testid = $testconv.id

$oldErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

foreach ($id in $testid) {
    try {
        $conv = Get-Content -Path "\\HDC-PRTG-03\System Information Database\Services\Device$id.Services" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json 
        $rpccheck  = $conv.message  # These look the same to me...
        $snmpcheck = $conv.message  # These look the same to me...
        $svcname   = $conv.data.displayname
        $svcstate  = $conv.data.properties.state

        $Matches = ($rpccheck | Select-String -Pattern "RPC*" -AllMatches)
        if ($Matches.Matches.Count) {
            Write-Host "RPC Not enabled"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "No RPC Enabled - Moving to Services List "
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
} 

$ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorAction
```

Instead of the try{}..catch{} you could also first test if a file with that name is present using `Test-Path` directly before doing the `Get-Content`.

Comment: @Samuel A Did this help??